# Lost 2 Rep points with nothing appearing

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

So yesterday while I was in the midst of answering some questions on SO, I mysteriously lost two reps points.  I checked my rep page and it didn't show any downvotes, etc...so I waited to see if anything would change with the recalc that takes place.

Nothing changed today, still missing the two points but I cannot figure out where I lost them from especially since there is no record that I can see.

It was weird because I got an upvote on an answer but then seemed to lose two rep points out of nowhere. I have looked on meta and saw the other questions about this possible behavior that is partly why I waited to post but I cannot see any reason why I lost the rep.

The rep was lost around this time frame yesterday:

[image: Reputation breakdown]

<sub>* Yes, I know my talent for drawing red circles is awesome.</sub>

Comment: Did you unaccept an answer?

Comment: nope, I didn't.

Comment: I applaud freehand drawings, but you call this a circle? On an equally serious note:  Did you check `show removed posts` on your reputation page?

Comment: @Dennis yes I checked the removed posts and it doesn't show anything unusual either, I tried checking everything before wasting people's time by posting this on meta.   I know its not a circle, I am obviously not very good at drawing without a mouse. I suck at it.

Comment: Still better than the non-freehand alternative. Resorting to wild guessing: Maybe a post of yours with a single downvote got undeleted. That doesn't show up in the reputation history (it just removes the `removed` event).

Comment: @Dennis Hmm, not sure.  I am def stumped.

Comment: @minitech: 10 minutes for 2 reputation, eh?

Comment: @animuson: I saw a freehand circle in distress.

Comment: @minitech what happened to my horrible circle??? I was proud of that terrible freehand drawing. :)

Comment: What was your rep before & after the lost 2 points?

Comment: @Emmett I don't know the exact amount but the issue came up when I was answering this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822912/how-can-i-format-a-datetime-to-varchar-with-the-format-dd-mmm-yyy

Comment: I notice this behavior a lot, myself. It's happened more than once and happens quite often (right now, I think it happens at every up vote on any of my posts)

Comment: I can't see negative reputation changes, but it's around here http://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=31

Comment: one possible reason is removal of some ancient post where one has got 2 points for approved [meta-tag:suggested-edits]. This happens to me sometimes, if memory serves turning on "show removed posts" in reputation tab allows to find it out

Answer (score 12):

Your rep did not disappear at all. The problem was really that a post that *you* edited was deleted by its owner or removed due to moderation reasons. This type of rep loss is not shown on your profile in your summary or time frame. It can only be found by first going to your reputation tab (trust me at this point) and finding three buttons that should say `post`, `time`, and `graph`. I supposed you only looked in the time part. Click the graph button and you should see a graph of your reputation. Green means rep went up and red means the total opposite. At the bottom left corner of the entire chart, find the box that says `show removed posts`. There is a box next to it. Click that box if it is unchecked. After that, you should see find the day you lost your rep, and click on it. If there was a deleted post, it will show up with a `-2` followed by a `removed` and what was removed. I hope this helps you!

Here is that page with the removed part I was saying (even though you lost ten rep for that): https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Slide the thing over to June 14 (2014), and find a small red line coming down. There are two of them, and one says `-10   removed    user was removed`.

Comment: This question is from 2012. You gotta look back a bit further than June 2014. :)

Comment: Err... nope http://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=31

Comment: Mystery solved!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened with me I was so disappointed why my reputation point is reducing after a certain time. But there is a check box on `activity` page *`show removed posts`* if you click on that you would got to know whats happening with reputation points

I am sharing the screen shot below:

[image]

Hope it would help to reduce confusion.